# Cannot create exponential trend line in Gnumeric

Tags: exponential, trend, gnumeric

I have a small dataset that I am trying to fit with a natural exponential trend line in gnumeric.

The data set is:

```
y1: 1.948, x1: 2.303
y2: 1.197, x2: 2.996
y3: 0.367, x3: 3.912
y4: 0.109, x4: 4.605
y5: -0.019, x5: 5.298
y6: -0.072, x6: 6.215
```

I want to fit it with a curve of the form: `y=a*e^(b*x)`

When I tried to fit this with an exponential in gnumeric I was not able to get it to create any trend line. It would not display anything.

I calculated the a and b parameters myself and plotted it in another application and it looked reasonable, but for some reason I cannot get gnumeric to generate this automatically.

Does anyone have any idea why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem myself, but I think I've solved it. You have to make sure that every cell in your data series contains only the data, and not any headers or similar invalid data. Otherwise, you can select "Skip invalid data" and your trendline should appear in the preview pane. At least, this worked for me.